# using jest in angular confused about tsconfig.spec.json and jest.config.js

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm using jest in an angular project.  In the project I have the following two files

tsconfig.spec.js
jest.config.js

in the tsconfig.spec.json I have the following

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "files": [
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

In the jest.config.json I have the following

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transform: {
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$":
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform",
  },
};
```

I feel like I am duplicating the effort here, can someone explain to me exactly how and what is tsconfig.spec.json used for and how this ties in with jest.config.json.  On top of this this is an angular project so in the angular.json I have the following entry

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run"
}
```

So essentially I have three config files and from what I understand the angular.json -> tsconfig.spec.js -> jest.config.json.  Is that correct or am I missing something and is there some way to simplify this ?